# Android Socket Connections

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception, freeze

Trying to run a loop to check if a IP is open.

```
for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
    String ip = "10.0.0." + z;
        try {
            log(ip);
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, MainActivity._util.getPort());
            // Handle Stuff when Exception NOT throw
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
}
```

log is a function I made (no errors there)

.getPort() is just a "global" port number I've defined 
**EDIT** : That returns 2683 (just a random number)

it is supposed to just catch the exception then move on with the for loop but that doesn't happen.

Currently this just prints:

```
10.0.0.0

10.0.0.1
```

and then freezes.

If anyone has any advice that would be great!

**EDIT**

- using socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout) method still didn't handle correctly
- This is in an AsyncTask extended class, in the doInBackground() method

Comment: the port you get here:***MainActivity._util.getPort()*** is any chance that that int change its value when you are in the for loop???

Comment: May be an exception when the ip is false ?

Comment: @jgm what do you mean with an false ip?

Comment: First off, try not to create a socket at each iteration. Further more, have a finally { socket.close() }

Comment: Where you call this code? is it in activity?

Comment: This code is in an extended AsyncTask class that gets executed in onCreate()

Comment: @NicolasSimon, I've tried just 'new Socket' without assigning anything, closing the Socket, adding finally, and it still doesn't work

Comment: @user3502489 How about this answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14035011/4706693

Comment: go to this link: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611593/send-text-from-android-to-pc-via-wi-fi-connection/40820861#40820861)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no socket server to listen those IP and ports. So your socket client will be freeze. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14035011/4497248) you should use another constructor for the socket and set timeout to prevent freezing.

```
for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
    String ip = "10.0.0." + z;
        try {
            log(ip);
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, MainActivity._util.getPort()), 1000);
            // Handle Stuff when Exception NOT throw
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
}
```